# Beginner RPG (game) random encounter

Tags: c#, ascii, console-application

I've encountered an issue while programming the RPG I'm working on. This issue happens when a random encounter is triggered.

It's important for me to tell you that the game is console based and the map I'm using is created with ascii characters. It uses w,a,s,d for movement. Whenever one of those keys is pressed, the player character moves one tile in that direction. You can hold the button to move in the corresponding direction at a higher speed.

In my code, I make sure to save the coordinates of the player when an encounter is triggered like this:

```
 oldx = Console.CursorLeft;
 oldy = Console.CursorTop;
 RandomEncounter();
```

With this, I trigger the random encounter subroutine, which looks as follows:

```
public static void RandomEncounter()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Random Encounter!");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WindowHeight = 33;
        Console.Clear();
        map = @"D:\personal\tests\Tests\ascii map tools\map1.txt";
        DrawMap(map);
        Console.WindowHeight = 32;
    }
```

This random encounter is just temporary, I will replace it with a battle of some sorts, but that's something I'll do later.

The map can be found here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wzsHS7iz9OS-WndihFFNOMXt4h18PPwl

Anyways, the issue happens when The random encounter is finished. The map will be redrawn, as shown in the code. Then, the cursor will be set at the right coordinates. However, it will immediately move about ten tiles in the direction of the button (w,a,s,d) that was last pressed when the random encounter happened.

The movement system that I use is a very simple one:

```
switch (input);
case 'w'
case 'a'
case 's'
case 'd'
```

This is not the entire chunk of input code, that wouldn't be nessecary I think.

So my question is: How do I stop the unwanted movement after a random encounter has occured?

Comment: Hi, seems like your console input buffer is not empty. Maybe [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9da27ed7-1453-414c-b17f-b056b83f5a21/ignoringdiscarding-stacked-keyboard-inputs-after-a-threadsleep?forum=csharpgeneral) thread helps you?

Comment: @nilsK perfect! that fixed it. Thank you very much